# SQL SUM - I don't want to loose precision when summing floating point data

Tags: sql, ms-access, floating-point, sum, decimal

I know when you work with **Money** it's better (if not imperative) to use `Decimal` data type, especially when you work with *Large Amount of Money* :). But I want to store price of my products as less memory demanding `float` numbers because they don't really need such a precision. Now when i want to calculate the whole **Income** of the products sold, it could become a very large number and it must have great precision too. I want to know what would be the result if I do this summation by `SUM` keyword in a SQL query. I guess it will be stored in a `Double` variable and this surely lose some precision. How can I force it to do calculation using `Decimal` numbers? Perhaps someone who knows about the *internals* of SQL engines could answer my question. It's good to mention that I use Access Database Engine, but any general answer would be appreciated too. This might be an example of the query I would use:

```
SELECT SUM(Price * Qty) FROM Invoices
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Invoices
```

`Amount` and `Price` are stored as `float(Single)` data type and `Qty` as `int32`.

Comment: The original decision to use 32-bit float creates a risk if you have any expensive items that have non-integer values. The cents digit stops being meaningful with 6 digits before the decimal point. It might be better to store, multiply, and sum the values as integer numbers of cents (or the appropriate smallest currency unit).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan No, there's no risk at my original decision. Because items are far from that expensive. They are all below 1000$ and no need to precision less than cents. But your point about storing `integer` cents seem interesting. Though I always have to do the adjunct work of converting them to $s when I show them to the user.

Comment: What's in the amount that gets stored as a float?

Comment: `Amount=Qty*Price` but `qty` is usually a small 2 3 max 10 number and if it was more (e.g. 100 for wholesale) then we wouldn't need precision (30.5 * 100 = 3050). So I think I can store `Amount` and `Price` safely as `float` numbers. float allows for 7 digits precision. So I can store 99999.99$. We don't really need more than that. The problem arises when you're doing summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, as *@Phylogenesis* said in the first comment, when I think about, we don't sell enough items to overflow the precision on a `double` value, just like items are not expensive enough to overflow the precision on a `float` value.As I guessed, I tested and found that if you run simple `SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Invoices` query, the result will be a `double` value. But following what suggested by **@Gordon Linoff**, the safest approach for obsessive-compulsive people is to use a cast to `Decimal` or `Currency(Access)`. So the query in Access syntax will be:

```
SELECT SUM(CCur(Price) * Qty)
FROM Invoices;

SELECT SUM(CCur(Amount))
FROM Invoices;
```

which `CCur` function converts `Single(c# float)` values to `Currency(c# decimal)`. Its good to know that conversion to `Double` is not necessary, because the engine does it itself. So the easier approach which is also safe is to just run the simple query.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do the calculation as a double, then cast one of the values to that type:

```
SELECT SUM(cast(Price as double) * Qty)
FROM Invoices;

SELECT SUM(cast(Amount as double))
FROM Invoices;
```

real double precision

Note that naming is not consistent among databases.  For instance "binary_float" is 5 bytes (based on IEEE 4-byte float) and "binary_double" is 9 bytes (based on IEEE 8-bytes double).  But, "float" is 8-bytes in SQL Server, but 4-byte in MySQL.  SQL Server and Postgres use "real" for the 4-byte version.  MySQL and Postgres use "double" for the 8-byte version.

EDIT:

After writing this, I saw the reference to Access in the question (this should really be a tag).  In Access, you would use `cdbl()` instead of `cast()`:

```
SELECT SUM(cdbl(Price) * Qty)
FROM Invoices;

SELECT SUM(cdbl(Amount))
FROM Invoices;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the choice is between a float and a 4-byte (unsigned) int (both requiring the same amount of storage in memory) there are pros and cons:

- The float cannot accurately handle cents assuming that a price has
  the format $$$$$.cc (1/100ths are not precisely representable in the
  floating-point - single as well as double - format), so this will
  introduce rounding errors which are usually unacceptable in
  money-related applications.
- The int - assuming that you express the price in cents - will allow
  precise values in the range -2^31 to 2^31-2^0 (about 2 * 10^9) cents for signed values
  and 0 to 2^32-2^0 (about 4 * 10^9) for unsigned. The downside is that it may feel
  "unnatural" to use cents instead of dollars and cents but this is
  mostly a problem inside the developers mind: the actual "problems" -
  if you wish to call them that - arise when printing the values in
  dollars and cents which require a slightly more complex formatting
  but this is a very small price in relation to how the rest of the
  application can be simplified.

Later, when summing or performing other calculations - the integer cent and quantity values are first converted to double precision floating-point. The double precision format allows expressing integer values (assuming integer cents) precisiely in the range -(2^53-2^0) to 2^53-2^0 which probably (you need to check) covers your needs. Keep in mind, though, that you will still have integer cents in the double which need to be converted to dollars and cents.

**EDIT_*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

"6-7 decimal digits of precision" is most easily explained by the range of integers representable in the single-precision format. Since the SP format significand is 24 bits long (1 implicit + 23 explicit) this allows integers in the range 2^0 to 2^24-2^0 or 1 to 16777215. 16777215 is more than six (999999) but less than seven (9999999) decimal digits, hence "6-7 decimal digits." The double-precision format features a 53 bit significand (1 + 52) which results in an integer range of 2^0 to 2^53-2^0.

The real SP precision is "24 sequential binary digits of precision."

If you can make do with cents in 50 unit increments your range in SP will be 2^-1 to 2^23-2^-1 or 0.5 to 8388607.5

If you can make do with cents in 25 unit increments your range in SP will be 2^-2 to 2^22-2^-2 or 0.25 to 4194303.75.

Comment: You said that in a number with the format $$$$$.cc 1/100th are not precisely represented, but the precision allows for 7 digits. Perhaps this is because of nature of floating point numbers. I mean some "cents" are representable, some not, depending on the specific numbers. _Can you elaborate on that ?_ and what about $$$$.cc ? I think at least cents could be accurate in this. Thanks.

Comment: The floating-point format is binary. Fractions may be formed by adding together negative powers of two: -1, -2, -3, -4, -5 etc resulting in 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125 etc. There is no combination of fractions resulting in exact cents except for 0.00 binary giving 0.00 decimal, 0.01 giving 0.25, 0.10 giving 0.5 and 0.11 giving 0.75.